# Copying ssh private key with finder, but can't see it with console

Tags: terminal, ssh

**Background:** I generated an additional ssh key-pair on my windows 7 workplace computer. I placed the corresponding public keys in my bitbucket.org and github.com account. I am using atlassian sourcetree as a git gui. I copied the private key into (my mac) the .ssh folder using the finder(drag and drop), and when I use the command `ls -lah` also `ssh-add -l` doesn't show the keys I copied.

I am using OSX v10.7.5

Also, I have heard of this thing called keychain access, but I am new to mac, and I don't know if this sort of thing is required to manage my ssh keys.

**Question:** What is the reason I cannot see my private keys in my `~/ssh` directory? How do I fix it so that I can add the new private key.

Answer (score 1):

From Terminal, type:

```
cd ~/.ssh
sudo ssh-add [keyname]
```

This will add the key to your computer for you.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. `no such file or directory`. Again, even when I use `cd ~/.ssh` `ls -la` I don't even see the key I am expecting. But when I look in the finder, I see `id_rsa_workplace` which is the name of the private key I am trying to add.

Comment: @DanielDropik What happens if you type `ls -l ` and then drag in the file from Finder? If you can see it from Finder maybe you're in the wrong directory since Finder doesn't show files with names that start with a dot.